# mix.ngTemplates is not a function()

Tags: laravel-elixir, angular-templatecache

I followed the short tutorial to install an html template cache package in my application: [laravel-elixir-ng-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-ng-templates) I installed and configured it exactly as show but now when I try to run gulp I get the following error:

[image]

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-sass-compass');
require('laravel-elixir-ng-templates');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.compass('app.scss');

    mix.styles([
            '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            '/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css',
            '/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css',
            '/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.css',
            '/angular-perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.css',
            '/snapjs/snap.css',
            '/angular-snap/angular-snap.min.css',
            '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
        ],
        'public/css/bower.css',
        'resources/assets/bower');

    mix.scripts([
            '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            '/angular/angular.js',
            '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            '/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js',
            '/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js',
            '/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
            '/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js',
            '/satellizer/satellizer.js',
            '/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js',
            '/angular-perfect-scrollbar/src/angular-perfect-scrollbar.js',
            '/snapjs/snap.min.js',
            '/angular-snap/angular-snap.min.js'
        ],
        'public/js/bower.js',
        'resources/assets/bower');

    mix.scripts([
            '/core/app.js',
            '/core/app.routes.js',
            '/controllers/ctrls.js',
            '/controllers/app.ctrl.js',
            '/controllers/auth.ctrl.js',
            '/directives/directives.js',
            '/directives/route-css-classes.js'
        ],
        'public/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/app');

    mix.ngTemplates('resources/assets/app/views/**/*.html', 'public/js/templates.js', {
        filename: 'templates.js',
        root: 'tpls/',
        module: 'tpls'
    });

});
```

Now I'm new to both gulp and elixir so I may be doing something wrong here though I cannot tell what.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, **Laravel** Mix ships with jQuery `autoloading` out of the box. All what you need is call `mix.autoload` before you try to compile other JavaScript files.

**For Example :**

```
mix.autoload({ 'jquery': ['window.$', 'window.jQuery'] }); 
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js') 
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I think **elixir** do the same. try to find a way how to call `autoload` function in elixir.